# Changing Column Datatype After Data Insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to localize a database, and my strategy involves taking all localizable strings out of my various tables, and putting them into another table containing a StringID, a CultureID and the LocalizedString, which is then referenced within the original table by the StringID.  The problem is that I need to change the datatype of the column containing the string from a varchar to an int and replace the string with its reference to the LocalizedStrings table.

I've already taken all my strings from the table and created entries in the LocalizedStrings table at this point using an `INSERT INTO` query.  And my current efforts to solve my problem look like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... 
INTO TempTable
FROM OriginalTable
INNER JOIN LocalizedStrings
ON OriginalTable.StringColumn = LocalizedStrings.LocalizedString

ALTER TABLE OriginalTable
DROP COLUMN StringColumn

ALTER TABLE OriginalTable
ADD NameStringID int

INSERT INTO OriginalTable (NameStringID)
SELECT StringID FROM TempTable

DROP TABLE TempTable
```

However due to various nightmarish dependencies, I'm getting all kinds of exceptions trying to do this.

My question is, is there an easier way?  I'd also considered just adding the new column and leaving the old one as a temporary workaround, but that's pretty messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE OriginalTable
ADD NameStringID int

update OT
set NameStringID = LS.NameStringID 
from OriginalTable OT
join LocalizedStrings LS on ls.StringColumn = OT.LocalizedString
```

You will need to repeat this process for every child table if they also used the StringColumn. 
You will also need to adjust all stored procedures, queries, ORM mappings to use the new colulm.

Then when all have been changed, run

```
ALTER TABLE OriginalTable
DROP COLUMN StringColumn
```

And of course dropp the column onthe child tables too if need be.

Comment: I had to split out the top and bottom half of your query into two queries (SQL Server Management Studio didn't like me running a query on a column that was just created in the same query), but otherwise this seems like the way to go, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all of your column contains integer values, what you can do is cast the column to integer, and create another one on the fly. Not sure if I am understand you correctly, but something similar to the following:

```
declare @test table(id varchar(50),name varchar(50))

insert into @test
select '1','Test 1'

insert into @test
select '2','Test 2'

select *, cast(id as int) as ConvertedToInt into #Result from @test

select * from #Result

drop table #Result
```